# Web Applications v/s SmartPhone Applications (Iphone, Windows Mobile, Android/Nexus Application)

Tags: iphone, android, web-applications, windows-mobile, smartphone

**Q:** How does **Web Applications** `differ` from **SmartPhone Applications** (Iphone, Windows Mobile, Android/Nexus Application) and in what `specific aspects` do they `differ` and in what degree  ?

Also for example,

**Q:** Why we need mobile version of Web Application like `gmail.com` or `bankofamerica.com` specifically for `smartphone devices` where we can access same `web applications` on `smartphone` using `internet connections` ? In what `aspect` do they `differ` and `why` do we have those `differences` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

native app pros

1. save internet bandwidth
2. app response is faster
3. have a richer feature (camera integration)

web app pros

1. no need to develop for every platform, more choice of development language, platform
2. no approve is needed from apple, faster deployment of new features

Comment: for your points on native app pros, do you think they will be irrelevant in the near future?  Within the next few years, we'll have abundant data bandwidth and better mobile browsers.  If a developer believes this, should he waste time learning N different mobile development platforms if they will all retire?  Cross platform development is such a headache

Comment: @John - there are still functions that cannot be used in web app environment, like camera (back and front faced). Looking back to desktop environment, i think the industry try to use web as much as possible as a platform, but we still have lots of installable apps/software for various reasons. They inter-changeable in most cases, but not all cases (in terms of functionality, user experience)

Answer (score 1):

For your second question:
Web application is designed and built for computers with more CPU power, memory and larger screen. Take  the MacBook i am using 2GB memroy, 2.16GHz Intel Core 2 Duo,13" screen  VS IPhone 3G. that has 128MB Memory. 620 MHz (underclocked to 412 MHz) .
Gmail on IPhone is optimized, eg, screen size might be tailored; some background task performed on computers might be disable on iphone,

Answer (score 0):

A native application has access to the phone's environment, and as such can integrate better to improve usability (an iPhone app can make use of multi-touch capabilities, the accelerometers, the camera, etc.).

A web application is, well, a web application. You have to open your browser first, interactivity is limited things like javascript or flash.

Comment: web app can also use the accelerometers, geo location

Comment: @joetsuihk I didn't realize that. I guess web sites now know both where I am and if I'm laying down or standing :P

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is that, the page should be as minimal as possible for the mobile devices. Not much details and plugins are not yet available for the smarphones. Moreover the network bandwidth for the mobile users rely that the data transfer is as minimal as possible. The service providers may also put some limitations to the data transfer over the internet using smartphones. For example, just have a look at these links([google web](http://www.google.com) and [google mobile](http://www.google.com/m)) from the mobile and pc and see the differences in their view for both the devices.

Due to the limitations in the contents that can be accessed by the browsers, there is still many limitations for web applications for mobile